# Word for "functionally equivalent"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I catch myself using this particular phrase quite a bit, but get asked frequently to explain it.

Is there a single word that encompasses the meaning behind it?

"It's as if.." comes pretty close, and everybody understands that, but I don't like how that sounds, and don't see myself switching to it.

Edit: not looking for another phrase.

Some context: Every time you go to your friend's place, their dishes are piled up. It might be a coincidence that the dishes are only piled up when you go, but to you it is functionally equivalent to them never washing the dishes.

Comment: I'd use "functionally equivalent".  If the listener doesn't understand that he's not apt to understand any other similar term.  (Though I don't understand how "functionally equivalent" is functionally equivalent to "It's as if..".)

Comment: "It's as if" sounds close an approximate equivalent, to me.

Comment: “functionally equivalent” is an excellent phrase.  You should use it all the time.

Comment: Can you give some context? That way perhaps pointers can be given.

Comment: What's a synonym for synonym?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more commonly used expression is:

"These/this are/is the same/equal; ***for all intents and purposes***."

Comment: Thanks. I think this really fits what I was going for. Not a word, but a great phrase regardless.

Answer (score 1):

***de facto***

meaning "from fact" as opposed to *de jure*, meaning "from law".

*Despite it's official name, the Democratic People's Republic of Korea is a de facto authoritarian state.*